# Why is this SQL statement very slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table with about 1 million records (running SQL Server 2008 Web). I've got a search routine which tries to match on product code as well as product description.
However in some circumstances it's very slow. Below is (cut-down) sql statement:

```
WITH AllProducts AS (
  SELECT       p.*, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) AS RowNumber
  FROM        Product AS p 
    WHERE p.IsEnabled=1 AND
    (
      p.BaseSku = 'KPK-3020QWC-C' -- this on its own is fast
      OR
      CONTAINS(p.FreeTextStrings, '"KPK-3020QWC*"') -- and this on its own is fast, but not both
    )
) SELECT * FROM AllProducts        
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

Note that if i just compare on [p.BaseSku = 'KPK-3020QWC-C'] or [CONTAINS(p.FreeTextStrings, '"KPK-3020QWC*"')] individually (but not both) its instant. And if i compare them together it takes ages (several minutes) - and returns just one row.

IsEnabled and BaseSku are indexed, and FreeTextStrings is FTS-indexed.

I remember this was working fineb efore.

Can anybody shed any light on this and suggest some solutions?

Execution plan file is available here: http://wiki.webgear.co.nz/GetFile.aspx?File=Temp%5cSearch%20Test.sqlplan.zip

Comment: Can you show us an execution plan from your SQL Server?

Comment: These problems started to occur after upgrading SQL 2005 to SQL 2008.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`or` is notoriously slow on SQL Server. It's aggravating, to say the least.

Try splitting it up into two queries with a `union`:

```
WITH AllProducts AS (
  select *, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) AS RowNumber
  from (
  SELECT       p.*
  FROM        Product AS p 
    WHERE p.IsEnabled=1 AND
      p.BaseSku = 'KPK-3020QWC-C' 
  UNION
  SELECT       p.*
  FROM        Product AS p 
    WHERE p.IsEnabled=1 AND
      CONTAINS(p.FreeTextStrings, '"KPK-3020QWC*"')
  )
) SELECT * FROM AllProducts        
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

Comment: Exactly, the "or" is most likely causing a table scan on the product table even if there are indexes on both BaseSku and FreeTextStrings... A union will turn that to index seek + index scan...   (assuming there are indexes covering those two columns)

Comment: I've tried that and it indeed has shown great improvements. I'll try this technique with the full sql statement.

Comment: Yep, this has solved it. However i think it's quite strange that the same statement worked very fast in SQL 2005 and is working slow in SQL 2008. May be this would be addressed in the next service pack?

Comment: @Muxa: They did make a lot of improvements with the compiler. `or` handling was not one of them. I'm with you, though. I sincerely hope this changes soon!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well:

```
WITH AllProducts AS (
  SELECT       p.*, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) AS RowNumber
  FROM        Product AS p 
    WHERE p.IsEnabled=1 AND
    (
      CONTAINS(p.BaseSku, 'KPK-3020QWC-C') /* instead of p.BaseSku = 'KPK-3020QWC-C' */
      OR
      CONTAINS(p.FreeTextStrings, '"KPK-3020QWC*"')
    )
) SELECT * FROM AllProducts        
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

(I already had BaseSku FTS-indexed)

Answer (score 0):

`Make sure all necessary indexes are in place.`  I had the same problem with an `or` clause in one of my queries and creating a NONCLUSTERED INDEX with INCLUDE columns fixed the performance.

*After further testing, it was the **INCLUDE columns** part of the index that really fixed the performance problem*.  Here's what I did to determine the problem and how to fix it:

**Use the Execution Plan to help you creating the missing indexes:**

Without the index the query was taking 2+ min when it should have ran in a few milliseconds. So I compared execution plans of the query with and without the `or` clause in SSMS and it wasn't obvious what I needed to do (mostly due to my lack of understanding the execution plans).

But if you look above the execution plan in green text, SSMS may tell you to create a nonclustered index.  Hmm... worth a shot.  So I created the index and problem solved! You can right click the "CREATE INDEX" query and select "Missing Index Details...".  This will open a new tab with the full query for you to run.  Just give it a name.