# OR Condition making the query execution slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute a query (in Oracle SQL) with a `WHERE` clause in it as follows:

```
    SELECT booking_line_id
FROM booking_line
WHERE    (booking_line_id in
  (SELECT sbli.booking_line_id
   FROM search_booking_line_index sbli,
     policy_record pr,
     policy_record_revision prr
   WHERE sbli.attribute_name = 2209
   AND sbli.policy_record_id = pr.policy_record_id
   AND pr.latest_revision_id = prr.policy_record_revision_id
   AND LOWER(prr.broker_reference) LIKE '%123%'));
```

Execution plan:

```
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |                        | 19027 |   334K|   455   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS          |                        | 19027 |   334K|   455   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|   2 |   VIEW                 | VW_NSO_1               | 19027 |   241K|   449   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE         |                        | 19027 |   798K|            |          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN          |                        | 19027 |   798K|   449   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN         |                        |   464 | 13456 |    31   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| POLICY_RECORD_REVISION |   464 |  9280 |    21   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| POLICY_RECORD          |  4067 | 36603 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN  | SBLI_ATTRIBUTE_CDX     |   166K|  2282K|   416   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  9 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN    | BOOKING_LINE_PK        |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

This query executes very fast and returns rows within no time. But if I add a `OR` condition as below, the query hangs (or is taking a very long time) :

```
    SELECT booking_line_id
FROM booking_line
WHERE 1=0 or   (booking_line_id in
  (SELECT sbli.booking_line_id
   FROM search_booking_line_index sbli,
     policy_record pr,
     policy_record_revision prr
   WHERE sbli.attribute_name = 2209
   AND sbli.policy_record_id = pr.policy_record_id
   AND pr.latest_revision_id = prr.policy_record_revision_id
   AND LOWER(prr.broker_reference) LIKE '%123%'));
```

Execution plan:

```
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                           |   166K|   811K|   484   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                        |                           |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | BOOKING_LINE_PK           |   166K|   811K|    66   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   NESTED LOOPS                 |                           |     1 |    43 |   419   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   4 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                           |     1 |    23 |   418   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN           | SBLI_ATTRIBUTE_CDX        |     1 |    14 |   417   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| POLICY_RECORD             |     1 |     9 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | POLICY_RECORD_PK          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | POLICY_RECORD_REVISION    |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | POLICY_RECORD_REVISION_PK |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Expected that this should take the same time as the first query. But surprisingly, it didn't.

Can anyone please help me with the reason for the same?

Comment: There's some info on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291975/why-is-this-sql-statement-very-slow) (top answer: "or is notoriously slow on SQL Server.")

Comment: @keyser5053: Does this apply equally to Oracle as it does MSSQL?

Comment: I've heard that it's an SQL problem, but don't take my word for it...

Comment: Do you have indexes on Table1 or Table2 ? check the execution plan to see what's the difference, maybe the optimizer decided not to use some index...

Comment: I added the exact queries and the execution plans. Please check. The indexes are in place

Answer (score 2):

In 11gR2 at least, the plans and the execution are exactly the same. Here's my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS SELECT * FROM dba_objects WHERE object_id IS NOT NULL;
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM dba_objects WHERE object_id IS NOT NULL 
                                                   AND object_type = 'VIEW';

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT table1_pk PRIMARY KEY (object_id);
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT table2_pk PRIMARY KEY (object_id);
```

The execution plan for the first query:

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE1
  2                    WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM TABLE2);

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2776518249
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |           | 31523 |  6772K|   584   (1)|
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN                  |           | 31523 |  6772K|   584   (1)|
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1    |   396K|    78M|   575   (1)|
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE1_PK |   396K|       |    77   (0)|
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN                  |           | 31523 |   400K|    10  (30)|
|   5 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE2_PK | 31523 |   400K|     7   (0)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   4 - access("OBJECT_ID"="OBJECT_ID")
       filter("OBJECT_ID"="OBJECT_ID")

SQL>
```

and for the second query:

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE1
  2             WHERE 1 = 0 OR OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM TABLE2); 

SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2776518249
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |           | 31523 |  6772K|   584   (1)|
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN                  |           | 31523 |  6772K|   584   (1)|
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1    |   396K|    78M|   575   (1)|
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE1_PK |   396K|       |    77   (0)|
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN                  |           | 31523 |   400K|    10  (30)|
|   5 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | TABLE2_PK | 31523 |   400K|     7   (0)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   4 - access("OBJECT_ID"="OBJECT_ID")
       filter("OBJECT_ID"="OBJECT_ID")
```

Comment: We are using Oracle10g and the execution plans are different.

Comment: Updated the execution plans in the main description

Answer (score 0):

Seems that becouse you make the server to change execution plan.
The first query is executed with inner join that's why it's so fast.
But in the second the process has to check the first condition and then make a select if needed. You can change the query like this:

```
select ... 
 from t
 left join t2
 where 1=0 or t2.id is not null
```